# How to do SELECT in a column with different parameter and aliases?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to create a report from this table. I need to get the data from different parameter in a same column.

```
ID_NUMBER     ID_DOCUMENT     DOCUMENT_NAME
     A001               1           DOC_A_1
     A001               2           DOC_A_2
     A001               3           DOC_A_3
     B001               1           DOC_B_1
     B001               3           DOC_B_3
```

The SELECT parameter are 1 and 2

Then, the SELECT output should be:

```
ID_NUMBER     DOCUMENT_1     DOCUMENT_2
     A001        DOC_A_1        DOC_A_2
     B001        DOC_B_1           NULL
```

my current query:

```
SELECT 
   tdoc_1.ID_NUMBER, 
   tdoc_1.DOCUMENT_NAME AS "DOCUMENT_1" 
FROM `document` 'tdoc_1'

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT 
     tdoc_1.ID_NUMBER,
     tdoc_2.DOCUMENT_NAME AS "DOCUMENT_2" 
  FROM `document` 'tdoc_2' 
  WHERE `ID_DOCUMENT` = '2'
) temp_doc ON tdoc_1.ID_NUMBER = temp_doc.ID_NUMBER
WHERE ID_NUMBER = 1
```

The data in the column is big, so, it's better to have a speedy query

Comment: Are there a finite number of `ID_DOCUMENT`?  So you would only want 2 columns or is it potentially limitless?

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @Martin I usually only take maximum 3 `ID_DOCUMENT` as parameter and yes there are many ID_DOCUMENT and DOCUMENT_NAME

Comment: @P.Salmon `Server version: 5.5.47-MariaDB - MariaDB Server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need some aggregation with pivoting logic here:

```
SELECT
    ID_NUMBER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID_DOCUMENT = 1 THEN DOCUMENT_NAME END) AS DOCUMENT_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ID_DOCUMENT = 2 THEN DOCUMENT_NAME END) AS DOCUMENT_2
FROM document
GROUP BY
    ID_DOCUMENT
ORDER BY
    ID_DOCUMENT;
```

If you want the document columns to be flexible, then you'll need a bit of dynamic SQL for that.  It can't be hard coded.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the data in one column, then `GROUP_CONCAT()` might do what you want:

```
select id_number,
       group_concat(document_name order by id_document) as documents
from document
group by id_number;
```

The advantage to this approach is that you can use a `where` clause to select the specific documents you want.  For your specific question (for `1` and `2`):

```
select id_number,
       group_concat(document_name order by id_document) as documents
from document
where id_document in (1, 2)
group by id_number;
```